# Make org-preview-latex-fragment stick

Tags: org-mode, latex

If I invoke `org-preview-latex-fragment` under one region, it destroys my previews in all other regions. Is there a way to make latex previews stick, so that previews are only removed when running `C-c C-c` a local (on point) or global "hide previews" command?

Comment: There is an option for set preview latex fragment at startup. Maybe it can help you.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like it is not possible to achieve this currently. First, 
 `org-preview-latex-fragment` always deletes all overlays before doing anything at all, see [Line 18329 in org.el](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/lisp/org/org.el#L18392).
In addition, `C-c C-c` also implements this behavior, see [Line 20313 in org.el](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/lisp/org/org.el#L20313).

However, I cannot see any compelling reason why `org-preview-latex-fragment` must delete all overlays before creating the current one. And I agree this is annoying behavior. Maybe it should be reported as a bug?